# Enviar múltiples archivos en React hacia el backend

Tags: reactjs

Mi componente "Gallery" tiene un array de archivos (photos) como estado, el cual envío a través de axios. Los datos llegan y los puedo guardar en el servidor satisfactoriamente, pero mi duda está en el código, ya que mapeo el estado y creo un nuevo FormData para cada elemento del array, y los envío uno por uno utilizando un `axios.post()` para cada item. Quisiera saber si hay una forma de poder enviar directamente ese array, utilizando un sólo `axios.post()`. Mi código es el siguiente:

En React:

```
try {
    this.state.photos.map( async onePhoto => { //Mapeo el array de fotos
        var formData = new FormData();         //Creo un nuevo FormData por cada foto encontrada
        formData.append('photo', onePhoto);
        await axios.post(this.URI, formData);  //Un post por cada fotografía, no sé si es correcto
    })
    this.setState({
        photos: []                             //Seteo el estado al finalizar
    })
}catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

En express:  (creo que es irrelevante, ya que mi duda está en el frontend, pero por las dudas lo muestro)

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, path.join(__dirname, '/public/uploads'))
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
});
app.use(multer({storage}).single('photo'));  //como ven, recibo las fotos una por una
//  app.use(multer({storage}).array('photos', 20)); //Está comentado porque no sé cómo enviar el array entero
```

Comment: Y si editas un poco tu funcion flecha: `async () = onePhoto =>`

Comment: Me tira error de compilación. ¿De igual forma no sería `const myFunction = async (parameters) =>{}` y luego llamarla dentro del map pasándole el item?

Answer (score 0):

Le estás pasando a multer el archivo a través del método `single`, eso no te permite gestionar varios archivos a la vez. Sin embargo, multer te permite recibir una lista de archivos a través del método `array`.

```js
app.post('/photos/upload', upload.array('photos', 12), function (req, res, next) {
  // req.files is array of `photos` files
})
```

En la parte front lo que haría sería pasarle directamente `this.state.photos`

```js
var formData = new FormData();         
formData.append('photos', this.state.photos);
await axios.post(this.URI, formData);
```

Comment: Exactamente eso ya hice: en el back utilicé el `upload.array('photos', 20)` y desde el front `formData.append('photos', this.state.photos)` y `await axios.post(this.URI, formData)` pero no me deja enviar el estado completo desde el `axios.post`. Voy a hacerlo de vuelta y te paso el error.

Comment: Comprueba no haya algún límite de tamaño de archivo u otra configuración que pudiera interferir.

Comment: Me corrijo, no surge ningún error :( Envío el `formData.append('photos', this.state.photos)` desde el front, el back incluso me responde con un 200, pero las fotos no se guardan. Si las envío de a una utilizando `upload.single('photos')` sí se guardan.
Haciendo las pruebas en insomnia sí puedo guardar las fotos, el problema está en el front. ¿Se puede en verdad hacer un `FormData('array' myArray)`?

Comment: por supuesto. te llega un array[] de archivos [multer.array (doc)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#arrayfieldname-maxcount)

Comment: De cualquier forma que lo haga, ya sea `axios.post(this.URI, formData)` o `axios.post(this.URI, this.state.photos)` el servidor recibe un array vacío. ¿Por qué será?

Comment: Tienes configurado el middleware? (body-parser)

Comment: No, sólo `multer`, `express.urlencoded` y `express.json`. Pero si puedo recibir un array utilizando la herramienta Insomnia entonces el problema no está en el backend. De igual forma voy a probar y te confirmo.

Comment: ¿body-parser no cumple la misma función que los métodos `urlencoded` y `json` de express?

Answer (score 0):

para que el formData tome las imágenes que se encuentren en un array y los convierta en binarios se necesita recorrer el array que contiene las imagenes e ir llenando el formData con la imagen y el nombre

React:

```
let formData = new FormData();
for (const e of files) { 
   formData.append('photos', e, e.name);
}
```

Nodejs:
Podes recibirlo como un campo que puede contener otros campos que no sean files o bien solamente el array de images como el código que esta comentado

```
app.use(multer({storage}).fields([{name: 'photos', maxCount:20}, {name: "title"}]));
```

> //  app.use(multer({storage}).array('photos', 20)); //Está comentado
> porque no sé cómo enviar el array entero